# How to convert array of string to nested JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to display all the files and folders present in the blob storage in my front end. for which I am using PrimeNG tree component. however, I am not able to convert my response to the format required by primeNG.

here is the actual response:

```
"filenames": [
"/30",
"/mtcagent.log",
"/spe9_xf.rst/bin/sbin/spe9_rgg-prop_ycoer.fbin",
"/spe9_xf.rst/bin/sbin/spe.fbin"
]
```

expected:

```
[
{"label": "30",
"Icon": "pi pi-folder"
},
{
"label": "mtcagent.log",
"Icon": "pi pi-folder"
},
{
"label": "spe9_xf.rst",
"Icon": "pi pi-folder",
"children": [
{
"label": "bin",
"Icon": "pi pi-folder",
"children": [
{
"label": "sbin",
"Icon": "pi pi-folder",
"children": [
{
"label": "spe9_rgg-prop_ycoer.fbin",
"Icon": "pi pi-file",
},
{
"label": "spe.fbin",
"Icon": "pi pi-file",
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
```

This is my code so far:

```js
var arr = [
  "abc.rft",
  "ccc.rft",
  "spe9_sgrid_long_rstcreation.rst/bin/sbin/spe9_batch-grid.dat.binfiles"
];
var arrOfObjs = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var obj = {
    "expandedIcon": "pi pi-folder-open",
    "collapsedIcon": "pi pi-folder"
  };
  obj.label = arr[i];
  arrOfObjs.push(obj);
}

arrOfObjs.forEach(e => {
  if (e.label.indexOf('/') == -1) {
  } else {
    var carray = new Array();
    var x = e.label.split('/');
    e.label = x[0];
    obj.label = e.label;
    carray.push(obj);
     console.log('carray', carray)
    e['children'] = JSON.stringify(carray);
    console.log('sss', arrOfObjs)
  }

});
```

Comment: can you please share your efforts

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shrutidevurkar/fbmuz89r/132/

Comment: How do you know `"/30"` is a folder and not a file?

Comment: here is my effort though its failing to form nested objects

Comment: in each string, always the last name is file name..

Answer (score 0):

You can use .map higher-order function to do this action.

Comment: good alternative but that still does not resolve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe use :

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(carray));